# Is it possible to say 'suspicion and anticipation (...) has reached'?

Tags: meaning, grammar

**In the article about Dismaland there is a paragraph saying:**

> Inside the walls of a derelict seaside swimming resort in Weston-super-Mare, UK, mysterious construction over the last month—including a dingy looking Disney-like castle and a gargantuan rainbow-colored pinwheel tangled in plastic—suggested something big was afoot. **Suspicion and anticipation surrounding the unusual activity attributed to fabled artist and provocateur Banksy has reached a Willy Wonka-esque fervor.** Well, if Banksy’s your bag, continue fervoring. If not, there’s more than a few reasons to continue reading.

I'm not sure if I understand the meaning of this bold sentence correctly. I tried to divide it into two sentences:

**The unusual activity (was) attributed to fabled artist and provocateur Banksy. 
Suspicion and anticipation has reached a Willy Wonka-esque fervor.**

But now I don't know - is it possible to use 'has' as a predicate for two things (suspicion and anticipation)?

Comment: The author is treating "suspicion and anticipation" as a single entity.  This is a legitimate approach, albeit one that some purists would object to.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm not a purist, but the author of the passage could use a dozen lashes in Trafalgar Square at noon for being a conceited moron.

Answer (score -1):

Good catch.

Apart from the fact that the passage is awfully worded, yes, the plural form is in order here.

Comment: Nah. It's just a stylistic choice. When the two words can easily be thought of as *a single combination*, such as [fame and fortune](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fame+and+fortune+has%2Cfame+and+fortune+have&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfame%20and%20fortune%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfame%20and%20fortune%20have%3B%2Cc0), it's perfectly okay to treat them as syntactically singular. Just because OP's example is clumsy doesn't alter the fact that the writer clearly intends *suspicion and anticipation* to be seen as a "natural" pair.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point, sort of; however, contrary to the author's intentions, __suspicion and anticipation_ are _not_ a natural pair.

Comment: That specific point is one of the reasons why I agree your "awfully worded" assessment.